# How can I remove this single point of failure from my application architecture?

Tags: architecture, high-availability

I have an application which currently has the following setup:

- Replicated MySQL DB
- Distributed Work Queue
- Several Work Queue Consumers/Workers
- Single producer which adds jobs to the queue (server in red below)

The setup looks something like this:

[image]

The **job producer** queries the database for new items which need to be added to its list of recurring jobs that need to be added to the work queue every N minutes.  This job producer is the only node in my whole architecture which if failed, would cause the entire process to fail.  I can have a DB server, a queue server, or several worker servers fail and the process would continue to operate.

How can I modify the job producer so that it isn't a single point of failure?  I don't know how to distribute the work it does, which is querying the database every N minutes and enqueuing new jobs to be processed.  It is a singular task.

I considered having multiple producers, and each producer would use modulus to only process 1/P jobs where P is the number of producers.

Something like:

```
itemsToBeProcess = db.FetchItems()
for (item in itemsToBeProcessed) {
    if item.id % producerNumber == 0) // Queue job
}
```

This would divide the work of the producers to multiple servers.  However, this still isn't ideal, because if a single producer goes down than 1/P worth of jobs will stop being processed.  So, it would still be a partial failure.

Can anyone give any guidance on how I can make this job producer not be a single point of failure in my application?

Comment: How do changes that require work to be queued get into the db?  Looking at the larger architecture, I'd be trying to remove the polling...

Comment: @ErikEidt this application will be used fetch RSS feeds.  The querying of the database is simply to check and see if new feeds have been added and need to be added to the producers list of known feeds .  Every feed is added to the work queue every N minutes to fetch the latest feed to check for updates.  I suppose I could remove the DB polling with some changes to the rest of the app to let the producer know more directly if new podcasts have been added.  However, I would still have my issue of the producer being a single point of failure.

Comment: I like that idea.  Further if the producer is simple, maybe its function can be moved back into the rest of the app as per above.  If it is complicated or needs shared state, you'll have to scale it out possibly with another queue in front of it and maybe with another db setup for it.

Comment: @ErikEidt the producer is simple, but *something* will have to be this periodic queuer.  The nature of this application is that these feeds must be polled every N minutes.  The only thing the producer has is a list of RSS feeds, and timestamps for when it last queued them.  It queues each feed after N minutes and updates the timestamp.   That is the part that I'm struggling to make highly available.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any specific reason to query db every N minutes? I would solve such problem in a way that instead of N minutes I would query for N items and change an item state (eg. "open" -> "in progress") using "[select for update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)"* (to make sure an item is processing (retrieve and update the state) by one and only one producer). Thanks to that you would be able to scale/provide FO etc. without any problem.